# Create future time stamps for each combination of parameters

Tags: r, machine-learning, timestamp, time-series

I am wondering how can I create the future time stamps for each combination of parameters (BranchId, Hour, weekdays)

```
BranchId      Hour   weekdays     ActivityDate     Total   
    1          11      3      2018-02-06T00:00:00   18
    1          11      3      2018-02-13T00:00:00   23
    1          12      3      2018-02-06T00:00:00   15
    1          12      3      2018-02-13T00:00:00   13
    1          13      3      2018-02-06T00:00:00   24
    1          13      3      2018-02-13T00:00:00   22
```

Currently I am only able to create future time stamps for one combination, as follow:

```
BranchId    Hour    weekdays    ActivityDate       Total
    1        11        3     2018-02-06T00:00:00Z   18
    1        11        3     2018-02-13T00:00:00Z   23
    1        11        3     2018-02-20T00:00:00Z   
    1        11        3     2018-02-27T00:00:00Z   
    1        11        3     2018-03-06T00:00:00Z   
    1        11        3     2018-03-13T00:00:00Z
```

The code is:

```
min.date <- min(data$ActivityDate)
max.date <- max(data$ActivityDate)


unique.time <- seq(from = min.date,  to = max.date, by = "week")

forecast.time <- seq(from = max.date, by = observation.freq, length.out = 4 + 1)[-1]
all.time <- c(unique.time, forecast.time)
all.time <- data.frame(BranchId = data$BranchId[1], Hour = data$Hour[1], weekdays = data$weekdays[1],ActivityDate = all.time)

# Join the combination with original data
data <- join(all.time, data, by = c("BranchId","Hour", "weekdays", "ActivityDate"), type = "left")
```

The result came out wrong when I applied this code on it, it would not create future time stamps for each combination:

```
BranchId    Hour    weekdays    ActivityDate      Total
   1         11        3    2018-02-06T00:00:00Z    18
   1         11        3    2018-02-13T00:00:00Z    23
   1         12        3    2018-02-20T00:00:00Z    
   1         12        3    2018-02-27T00:00:00Z    
   1         13        3    2018-03-06T00:00:00Z    
   1         13        3    2018-03-13T00:00:00Z
```

Do I need to generate multiple functions or for loops to approach it?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking whether this can be done by python or not.

Comment: Both R and python can achieve

Comment: @Wen How can I modify the code above to achieve? Can you give me some advises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R with complete

```
df%>%group_by(BranchId,Hour,weekdays)%>%complete(ActivityDate = seq.Date(min(ActivityDate), min(ActivityDate)+42, by="week"),fill=list(Total=0))
# A tibble: 21 x 5
# Groups:   BranchId, Hour, weekdays [3]
   BranchId  Hour weekdays ActivityDate Total
      <int> <int>    <int>       <date> <dbl>
 1        1    11        3   2018-02-06    18
 2        1    11        3   2018-02-13    23
 3        1    11        3   2018-02-20     0
 4        1    11        3   2018-02-27     0
 5        1    11        3   2018-03-06     0
 6        1    11        3   2018-03-13     0
 7        1    11        3   2018-03-20     0
 8        1    12        3   2018-02-06    15
 9        1    12        3   2018-02-13    13
10        1    12        3   2018-02-20     0
```

Comment: Thank you Wen! I am wondering what if the weekdays are different, which means the last ActivityDate would not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using R, you can use the following code to create extra dates with a weekly interval. Using the function `pad` from the package `padr` you can define the interval with which to add dates to a data.frame. Use the group option to tell the function which variables should be used to create the new timelines or fill in missing dates. You can specify start and end dates so everything between those will be taken, otherwise it will be the `min` and `max` dates available in the data.frame.

```
min.date <- min(df$ActivityDate)
max.date <- as.Date("2018-03-13T00:00:00Z")

library(padr)

df <- pad(df, interval = "week" , start_val = min.date, end_val = max.date, group = c("BranchId", "Hour", "weekdays"))

# this step can be skipped if you want to keep NA's instead of 0 
df <- fill_by_value(df, value = 0)
df

   BranchId Hour weekdays ActivityDate Total
1         1   11        3   2018-02-06    18
2         1   11        3   2018-02-13    23
3         1   11        3   2018-02-20     0
4         1   11        3   2018-02-27     0
5         1   11        3   2018-03-06     0
6         1   11        3   2018-03-13     0
7         1   12        3   2018-02-06    15
8         1   12        3   2018-02-13    13
9         1   12        3   2018-02-20     0
10        1   12        3   2018-02-27     0
11        1   12        3   2018-03-06     0
12        1   12        3   2018-03-13     0
13        1   13        3   2018-02-06    24
14        1   13        3   2018-02-13    22
15        1   13        3   2018-02-20     0
16        1   13        3   2018-02-27     0
17        1   13        3   2018-03-06     0
18        1   13        3   2018-03-13     0
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(BranchId = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                     Hour = c(11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L), 
                     weekdays = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                     ActivityDate = as.Date(c("2018-02-06T00:00:00", "2018-02-13T00:00:00","2018-02-06T00:00:00", 
                                      "2018-02-13T00:00:00", "2018-02-06T00:00:00", "2018-02-13T00:00:00")), 
                     Total = c(18L, 23L, 15L, 13L, 24L, 22L)), 
                .Names = c("BranchId", "Hour", "weekdays", "ActivityDate", "Total"),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you, phiver. I am geting this error `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`, I think it came from as.Date.  And what if the weekdays are different, which means the last of activitydate would not be the same, how can I modify the max.date?

Comment: Be aware that my data.frame is called df, not data. The error is probably at the min.date line. You can choose whatever you want for max.date. But if you have different weekdays, you might want to extend your activity dates first, then calculate the weekday number.

Comment: Yes, I already changed them and made sure each of them point to the right thing, but this was what I got, `invalid tz` ...